# C# XNA React to Sub-Bass frequency of Song

Tags: c#, xna

I'm currently programming a game in XNA and I want the screen to react to the background music, but only the sub bass (20 to 60 Hz). I already figured out how the screen will react, but my attempt to react to the sound didn't work that great.

I tried it with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sicNHbriHTg), but it only taught me how I could use the current Wave Form of the Song.

So how can I analyze the frequency between 20 and 60 Hz (sub bass), so that the screen can react to it?

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? It seems, you just want to interpret [`VisualizationData.Frequencies`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.visualizationdata.frequencies.aspx).

Comment: [What have you tried that isn't working](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?